# Screen dims off and locks on VLC 3.0.0

Tags: 16.04, vlc, snap

I installed vlc 3.0.0 via snap and now I'm facing an issue of the screen dimming and locking even when I'm watching a video.
There was no such issue on the previously installed version of vlc 2.2.2.
Can anyone help out with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The switch to deactivate the screensaver and screen locking setting has been moved in the UI. You now need to select `All` settings in the bottom switch in the settings dialog and select `Video` from the module tree an the left. There you find the setting to deactivate the screensaver/screen locking.

This doesn't seem to work if VLC is accessed through SSH which might be a bug or a limitation of SSH windows in general.